# perl reference clarification needed

Tags: perl, reference

Straight from https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

I don't understand below

```perl
 $$hashref{"KEY"}   = "VALUE";       # CASE 0
 ${$hashref}{"KEY"} = "VALUE";       # CASE 1
 ${$hashref{"KEY"}} = "VALUE";       # CASE 2
 ${$hashref->{"KEY"}} = "VALUE";     # CASE 3
```

What is the difference between case 1 and 2?

I am thinking anything inside `${}` is a pointer to some address so it's like

```perl
my $hashref = \%hash;
```

`${$hashref}{"KEY"}` is really `$$hashref{"KEY"}` and this is dereferencing `\%hash` and looking up it's `"KEY"`

`${$hashref->{"KEY"}}` .. I would think is..  ?? I thought the rule was the bind closest to the left so I thought this also became `$$hashref->{"KEY"}`. which is same as `${$hashref}{'KEY'}`.   Am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Case 0 and 1 are equivalent, these you have understood correctly.

Case 2 is a bit subtle:

```
${$hashref{"KEY"}} = "VALUE";
```

First, this executes `$hashref{"KEY"}` which looks up the `"KEY"` in a hash variable called `%hashref`. Despite its name it is a hash, not a hash reference! This returns a value in that hash.

Next, we dereference that value in the hash as a scalar reference: `${ ... }`.

Finally, we assign a `"VALUE"` to the scalar reference target.

Case 3 is similar, but actually uses a hash reference.

If we rewrite Case 2 and 3, their relation might be clearer:

```
{ # Case 2
  my %hash;
  ${ $hash{"KEY"} } = "VALUE";
}

{ # Case 3
  my %hash;
  my $hashref = \%hash;
  ${ $hashref->{"KEY"} } = "VALUE";
}
```

Additional remarks:

- The `${ … }` dereference operator does not bind closest to left, it *contains* the value that will be dereferenced. The `$$foo` form is a short form of the `${ … }` dereference operator if the reference is a normal scalar variable, as opposed to a more complex expression. This is not only the case for scalar references but also array refs (`@{ … }` and `@$foo`) and hash refs (`%{ … }` and `%$foo`).
- The sigil ($ % @) of a dereference operator is not the type of the reference, but depends on whether we are accessing one or more values in the reference target.

  When we access a single value in a hash `%hash` this looks like `$hash{"KEY"}`.

  When we access a single value in a `$hashref`, this looks like `$hashref->{"KEY"}` or `${$hashref}{"KEY"}` or `$$hashref{"KEY"}`.

  Despite the `$` there is no scalar reference here. The scalar dereference operator `${ … }` is essentially a separate operator from the hash reference subscript operator `${ … }{ … }`.
- The expression `$$foo->{"KEY"}` features a scalar reference to a hash reference! Firs the scalar reference `$foo` is dereferenced `$$foo` to a hash ref, in which a value `…->{"KEY"}` is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between cases 0 and 1 is that in case 1 a block of code may be used inside `${}`, which returns a hashref.  Some things work without a `{}`, like the specific example in case 1, but some can't. It says [elsewhere in perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References)

> Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a simple scalar variable containing a reference of the correct type
>   ...
>   **Anything more complicated than a simple scalar variable must use methods 2 or 3 below.**
>   ...
>   Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can **replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference** of the correct type.

(emphasis mine)

An example

```
sub get_hr { return { a => 1, b => 2 } }

say ${ get_hr() }{a}
```

may go a bit overboard (and is unfit for production) but hopefully conveys it.

A lot of other clarifications are provided in the answers [by amon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721280/4653379) and [by ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721942/4653379).

Also see [Using references in perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Using-References) and 
[Caveats on precedence in perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#CAVEAT-ON-PRECEDENCE)

Answer (score 0):

- `$NAME` (e.g. `$foo`) is a scalar variable.
- `$BLOCK` (e.g. `${ $ref }`) is a scalar variable (via a reference).
- `$$NAME` (e.g. `$$ref`) is short for `${ $NAME }` (e.g. `${ $ref }`).

Similarly,

- `$NAME{EXPR}` (e.g. `$foo{bar}`) is a hash element.
- `$BLOCK{EXPR}` (e.g. `${ $ref }{bar}`) is a hash element (via a reference).
- `$$NAME{EXPR}` (e.g. `$$ref{bar}`) is short for `${ $NAME }{EXPR}` (e.g. `${ $ref }{bar}`).

So,

- `$$hash_ref{"KEY"}` is short for `${ $hashref }{"KEY"}`
- `${ $hash_ref }{"KEY"}` is a hash element.
  `$hashref` is a reference to the hash.
- `${ $hash{"KEY"} }` is a scalar variable.
  `$hash{"KEY"}` is a reference to the scalar.
  `%hash` is a hash.
- `${ $hash_ref->{"KEY"} }` is a scalar variable.
  (`$hash_ref->{"KEY"}` is a nice way to write `$$hash_ref{"KEY"}`.)
  `$hash_ref->{"KEY"}` is a reference to the scalar.
  `$hash_ref` is a reference to a hash.